# Confused about Object.defineProperties function

Tags: javascript, function

So, I have an element prototype function called `hasClass`.

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) 
{
    if  (className && typeof className === "string") 
    {
        if (this.classList) 
        {
            return this.classList.contains(className);
        } 
        else
        {
            return new RegExp(className).test("" + this.className + "");
        }
    }    
};
```

Now, since I have to define multiple functions and the code will become pretty messy then I thought, why not use `Object.defineProperties` function; same function with the function:

```
Object.defineProperties(Element.prototype, {
    "hasClass": {
        get: function (className) 
        {
            if (className && typeof className === "string")
            {
                if (this.classList)
                {
                    return this.classList.contains(className);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new RegExp(className).test("" + this.className + "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The first function works fine as it should.
However, when defining same function with `Object.defineProperties` my Firefox console starts spamming: *`TypeError: $test.hasClass is not a function`* (Where `$test` is element choosen with selector). This error does not appear when using normal, first example of function, while it appears when using the lattest one.

So the question is. Why it does throw such error while it should not?

Oh yeah, funny thing is that when I use the second function with `console.log` like this:

```
Object.defineProperties(Element.prototype, {
    "hasClass": {
        get: function (className) 
        {
            /*if (className && typeof className === "string")
            {
                if (this.classList)
                {
                    return this.classList.contains(className);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new RegExp(className).test("" + this.className + "");
                }
            }*/
            console.log( "HI");
        }
    }
});
```

Then the console says this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6X2p.png

I am confused.

Comment: Don't call it as a function.

Comment: What do you mean by not calling it as a function?

Comment: Okay, now I got it. get returns for variable, but I call it as function, thus I have to search for certain alternatives here.

Comment: Aside from get and set...I do not know...seems like I have to use first function example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mis-using the property `get` you should be using `value` otherwise `hasClass` will be the value **returned** from the `get` function.

**Replace `get` with `value`**

```
Object.defineProperties(Element.prototype, {
    "hasClass": {
        value: function (className) 
        {
            /*if (className && typeof className === "string")
            {
                if (this.classList)
                {
                    return this.classList.contains(className);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new RegExp(className).test("" + this.className + "");
                }
            }*/
            console.log( "HI");
        }
    }
});
```

[Refer to documentation on `defineProperty` even though you're using `defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

The problem: in your version the value of `hasClass` will be undefined because you haven't returned anything from the get function the last statement is `console.log( "HI");` if you put `return {};` after that, `hasClass === {}`

Comment: Wow, thank you. It works no when I replaced get with value. Thanks!

Comment: @user3595905 you might also want to put `enumerable: false` and `writable: true` just to make it act exactly like native methods

Comment: {IMHO} this is a mis-use of `Object.defineProperty`. The semantics of above `hasClass` is not like a typical property. So this answer is just a workaround not to get a `TypeError`, but it's not leading to good JavaScript.{/IMHO}

Comment: @hgoebl I answered the question, however, if OP is not using `enumerable: false` then yes this is pretty pointless, but he **should** be using `Object.defineProperty` with `enumerable: false` to achieve what he's trying to achieve

Comment: I would say that at start I was thinking about using extend function, however then I started looking around if there are any better ways doing it like a native way and hence why I ended up with `Object.defineProperties`, which now after certain coding looks...useless. I think I will stay with simple extending rather than using some unripe native methods here.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.defineProperty` and `Object.defineProperties` are not meant to define getter functions with params. In your case, just do it as in your first example (or look below, see Edit).

You can understand Object.defineProperty as a way to "intercept" the plain set/get action, but in the code where you get or set the property you can see no difference to "public" properties.

```
obj.abc = 'value';    // <-- set function called
console.log(obj.abc); // <-- get function called
```

There are no braces `()` - the functions are called transparently.

In case you really have properties, be careful not to run into recursive calls when the property you want to hide is actually as well public. See [JS defineProperty and prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047809/js-defineproperty-and-prototype)

**Edit**

As I understand your question, you're looking for a less verbose way to add functions to a prototype.
Many JavaScript libraries have a way to copy some properties from one object to another:

- jQuery: [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)
- Underscore/Lodash: [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)
- Leaflet: [L.extend](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#util-extend)
- sure there are many more (and maybe a modern version of ECMAScript already has such a utility method)

Here you have a very basic extend function, if you don't have one of those libraries at hand:

```
function extend1(dest, src) {
    var i;
    for (i in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            dest[i] = src[i];
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Now you could extend your prototypes like this:

```
extend1(Element.prototype, {
    hasClass: function (className) {
        /* the body */
    },

    methodFoo: function (arg1, arg2) {},

    methodBar: function () {},
});
```

I think, for methods this is a better way than using `Object.defineProperty`. For real property definitions, take `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take your tips and explanation. And again, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is true that I was looking for a less verbose way to do that. In-fact I find the extending way better now after messing around with `Object.defineProperties`. Really.
Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: You're welcome. Are you looking for alternative solutions? If not, you may consider marking the answer as correct and/or helpful.