# Error.prototype.toString() will throw a TypeError if I define the "name" property with Object.defineProperty()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've reduced the code to a minimum:

```
var util = require('util');

function ErrorDecorator(error) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.error = error;
}

util.inherits(ErrorDecorator, Error);

Object.defineProperty(ErrorDecorator.prototype, 'name', {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
        return this.error.name;
    }
});

var e = new ErrorDecorator(new Error());

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
console.log(e.toString());
```

#### Edit

I've come across [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14053800/997087) which suggests that I use `Object.defineProperty` in the constructor instead of on the prototype. I do not fully understand why, but I can only assume that when I define `name` on the prototype that it's called "statically" and not with the instance as its context?

TLDR this code works:

```
var util = require('util');

function ErrorDecorator(error) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.error = error;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function () {
            return this.error.name;
        }
    });
}

util.inherits(ErrorDecorator, Error);

var e = new ErrorDecorator(new Error());

// Error
console.log(e.toString());
```

#### Edit 2

Even though I've found a solution I'm still interested in knowing why my first code example doesn't work, and if what I'm doing is against best practices.

Comment: Are you sure `e` isn't `undefined` when you make your call to `console.log()`?  Set a breakpoint on that last line and analyze `e` when the application breaks.

Comment: It is defined. This is the exact code that I run to reproduce the error. Running `console.log(typeof e)` right before the other `console.log` will display `object`.

Comment: Just fyi: `console.log(e.name)` will output `Error` as expected.

Comment: @raina77ow I'm sure you answered my question correctly and completely, but I do not understand. Are you saying that `toString` is called more than once, and only one of those times with the `ErrorDecorator` prototype?

Comment: Actually no. Replacing the `get` method with `console.log('get')` and `return 42` will only output once.

Comment: @Vague No, it's called just once actually. It seems to be a bug in Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
var x = new Error();
var y = Object.create(x);
y.props = {
  name: 42
};
var z = Object.create(y);
Object.defineProperty(y, 'name', {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
        console.log('Is it Z?', this === z);
        console.log('Is it Y?', this === y);
        return this.props.name;
    }
});
console.log(z.toString());
```

It's tricky: when `toString` is called on an object that a) doesn't have its own implementation of `toString` and b) has `Error` instance in its prototype chain, it follows the algorithm described [**in the standard**](https://es5.github.io/#x15.11.4.4):

> **15.11.4.4 Error.prototype.toString ( )**
>
> The following steps are taken:
>
> - Let `O` be the `this` value.
> - If `Type(O)` is not `Object`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> - Let `name` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument "name".
> - If `name` is `undefined`, then let name be "Error"; else let name be `ToString(name)`.

The problem is that for some reason nodejs (0.10.33) seems to make a step up the prototype chain when in that getter: the results are `false` and `true` accordingly. Both Firefox and Chrome correctly use `z` as getter context.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to explain this to me. Honestly I'd like to keep asking why node does this, and if it's fixed in a newer version - but it's too much to ask. I am content in knowing that there might be a bug in NodeJSs implementation of `Error.prototype.toString` and that there is a workaround by defining the property for each instance individually. I'm using version 0.10.40 btw.