# Object.defineProperty with constructor function and prototype

Tags: javascript, properties

I just found out about [`Object.defineProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965578%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and as I'm most familiar with C# I'd like to use an accessor property with my constructor function, for example:

```js
function Base(id) {
   var _id = id;

   Object.defineProperty(this,"ID",{
       get: function() { return _id; },
       set: function(value) { _id = value; }
   })
}

function Derived(id, name) {
   var _name = name;

   Base.call(this,id);

   Object.defineProperty(this,"Name",{
      get: function() { return _name; },
      set: function(value) { _name = value; }
   })
}

Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.constructor = Derived;

var b = new Base(2);
var d = new Derived(4,"Alexander");

console.log(b.ID);
console.log(d.ID, d.Name);
d.ID = 100;
console.log(d.ID, d.Name);
```

This prints:

> 2
>   
>  4 "Alexander"
>   
>  100 "Alexander"

But I'm very confused about this, for example [this answer with a very high score](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18557503/3410196) encourages above approach, while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181232/3410196) says it will eat up all memory because the functions will be recreated for every object I instantiate. It suggests the following approach instead:

```
var Base = function(id){this.__id = id}
Player.prototype = {
   get ID(){
      return this.__id;
   },
   set ID(value){
      this.__id = value;
   }
}

var p = new Player();
p.ID = 2;
alert(p.ID); // 4
```

However this approach also creates another public property `__id` which seems less than ideal to me (the properties in my example are "privileged" as it's apparantly called in javascript, so no extra public property needed).

Can someone please explain which approach is the right one for me? Right now I'm **totally lost** in the javascript documentation jungle. I very much like the `Object.defineProperty` approach because the code feels very clean to me and I can use it with inheritance. But if it's true that the functions get recreated for every object I might need to consider the second approach?

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript!  While I have nothing to back it up (hence a comment, not an answer), modern JS engines are very good - while it _appears_ you have multiple functions being created in the first example, because the spec _says_ that's what happens, I wouldn't be at all surprised that internally the engine is smart enough to reuse the "same" function in memory.  Engines only have to make it look like things behave as per the spec - internally they can do whatever they like to get the job done.

Comment: I second James Thorpe. Apart from that, AFAIK `prototypes` memory reuse was a lot more relevant in the 90s, when memory was still pretty sparse. These days, unless you create hundreds of thounsends of instances, there is not much to be gained. (I don't have a source to back this up either though).

Comment: @JamesThorpe So it still *could* be happening that I create a new function for every object? @@nils That is true, I suspect I will only need to create ~100 objects maximum. It's astonishing how hard it is to find clear documentation on this :/

Comment: Yes - it could still be creating duplicate functions, all depends how good/agressive the engine is at optimising.  I would suspect this use case would be a good one for them to target though, it's not exactly uncommon.  At 100 objects though, you really don't need to worry.

Comment: @JamesThorpe What do you think of the second approach by the way? Imagine I *do* have to create thousands of objects, would that be the optimal approach?

Comment: If you're ok exposing the private parts of your object publicly, and can stop yourself being tempted to access them directly to fix that annoying bug 3 months down the line, it's also fine :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks a bunch (and nils you too), if any of you would want to write that as an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: Are you on an environment that supports ES classes? Would that improve your situation?

Comment: You must choose: shared methods with public data, or copied methods with private data. See [javascript - accessing private member variables from prototype-defined functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/436120/1529630), there is no perfect way to do that.

Comment: @Oriol That's really unfortunate about javascript in my opinion :/ I do however love to keep my backing fields "private" in a closure so I'll just stick with the first way of properties. I guess it won't result in too big of a performance hit (or let's hope so! )

Comment: @Paarth I'll be honest, I didn't know they exist so I had to look them up, but it seems to be some new feature. A lot of the clients of the company I work for use ancient browsers (sad I know) so I won't touch that I think. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @Paarth: Since classes are just syntactic sugar, they don't really solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone please explain which approach is the right one for me?

Don't use `Object.defineProperty` at all. You absolutely don't need property descriptors here, and your getters and setters don't do anything special. Just use a simple normal property. It will be faster and better optimised than anything else you are concerned about.

```
function Base(id) {
    this.ID = id;
}

function Derived(id, name) {
    Base.call(this,id);
    this.Name = name;
}

Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

> If it's true that the functions get recreated for every object I might need to consider the second approach?

Yes, that's true, but negligible. You should not micro-optimise prematurely. You're going to know when you really need it, and then you still can easily swap the implementation. Until then, go for clean and simple code.

Comment: In my real application a lot of things are interweaved so I certainly do need properties, I just gave a simple example sorry if that wasn't clear. After the discussion in the comments I totally agree with your 2nd point though. The first way to define properties is very elegant and readable so I'll go with that :)

Comment: It's always comforting to know you can lean towards clean code instead. You'll know when you have to micro-optimize. i.e. if you need a ridiculous amount of objects to be created on the fly.

Comment: What if we need to define properties in some case?

Comment: @zwcloud Then do define them if you need to?

Comment: @Bergi Could we define a property via `Object.defineProperty` on an object `obj` created by `var obj = new MyObject();` that acts as a member of `MyObject`? I mean the property itself will be shared between different instances of `MyObject`, the value of the property will not be shared.

Comment: @zwcloud Do you want to use an accessor property or a data property? Of course you can define properties either on the prototype or on the instance.

Comment: @zwcloud You might want to [ask a complete question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) demonstrating what you need (and for what) and how you tried to use `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late to the party, but there are a couple of small things I would like to point out here.

First, you're defining own properties *inside the constructor*, which is fine for instance specific properties and properties that should not be shared with other instances, but not for getters, setters and methods. Instead you should define those on the prototype of your function.

I understand your question like this

## How do you make real PRIVATE properties?

It is easy, and it works in all browsers. First we'll elaborate on Object.defineProperty, and the derived Object.create, Object.defineProperties.

### The *prototype* of javascript *object* definitions

Modern javascript allows some "syntactic sugar" for declaring classes, but *every **proud developer** should understand* how it really works.

**First** There are *no classes*. Javascript doesn't have classes. It has *prototypes*, which are not *classes*. The *resemble* classes, so in my naive stubborness, I took several classes to find the truth, and I objected and objected - and I got all the way to the bottom. There were no classes.

Let `you` be the object. If `you` or `your prototype` can't answer a question, then your `prototypes´ prototype` will be asked, and then your `prototypes´ prototypes´ prototype` will be asked, and on we go until there are no more prototypes to ask.

All those prototypes *are still objects*. This algorithm illustrates it:

```
// Friendly version
function askQuestion(askee, question) {
  do {
    if (askee.hasOwnProperty(question)) {
      return askee[question];
    }
  } while (askee = Object.getPrototypeOf(askee))
}
```

#### ECMAScript 6 (boring)

> To illustrate the syntax of "modern javascript" I'll digress:
>
> ```
> class Tortoise extends Turtle {
>
>   constructor() {
>     while (this.__proto__) {
>       this.__proto__ = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.__proto__);
>     }
>   }
>
>   #privateProperty = "This isn't a comment"
>
>   get __proto__() { return Object.getPrototypeOf(this); }
>
>   set __proto__(to) { Object.setPrototypeOf(this, to); }
>
> }
> ```
>
> This does not work in all browsers. It also doesn't work in any browser. It's just to show the syntax.

It has been claimed that the above is simply syntactic sugar on top of old-school javascript, but when it comes to extending native objects it suspect that there is more to it than meets the eye.

Even if "modern javascript" (ECMAScript 6) allows us to write classes like above, you should want to *understand it*.

> *Also, the modern javascript combined with the stubbornness of Internet Explorer 11 forces us to use ***babel***, an awesome tool with incredible powers that is so ***incredibly advanced*** and flexible that the probability of such a tool to even exist at all, by mere coincidence, is infinitely improbable.*
>
> *The very existence of the tool is proof that God exists which I am sad to say, also proves that God does not exist.*
>
> ---
>
> WTF?? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) and [there](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Babel_Fish#Philosophical_Implications), and [there](https://babeljs.io/).

#### Popping the hood

Don't create REUSABLE properties in the constructor. A function that is used by many instances should not be assigned in the constructor.

**Real Version**

```
function Base(id) {
  // GOOD
  this.id = id;

  // GOOD, because we need to create a NEW array for each
  this.tags = [];

  // Okay, but could also just be in the prototype
  this.numberOfInteractions = 0;

  // BAD
  this.didInteract = function() {
    this.numberOfInteractions++;
  }
}
```

**Sugar Coated**

```
class Base {
  constructor(id) {
    // GOOD
    this.id = id;

    // GOOD, because we need to create a NEW array for each
    this.tags = [];

    // Okay, but could also just be in the prototype
    this.numberOfInteractions = 0;

    // BAD
    this.didInteract = function() {
      this.numberOfInteractions++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Improved real version**

```
function Base(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.tags = [];
}
Base.prototype.numberOfInteractions = 0;
Base.prototype.didInteract = function() {
  this.numberOfInteractions++;
}
```

**Improved sugar coated version**

If you insist on sugar, and you like to write more lines of code and some extra labor after you're done writing the code, you can install babel and write your code like below.

It will make slightly larger and slower script files - unless you don't really need to support all browsers.

```
class Base {

  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tags = [];
  }

  numberOfInteractions = 0;

  didInteract() {
    this.numberOfInteractions++;
  }

}
```

#### Inheritance ABC

Inheritance in EcmaScript is very simple, once you truly understand it!

TLDR: If you want the above class to extend another class, you can do this one-liner:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Base.prototype, Parent.prototype);
```

This should work everywhere. It does essentially `Base.prototype.__proto__ = Parent.prototype`.

**`Base.prototype` vs *instance prototype***

All objects in javascript have an *instance prototype*. It is the *instance prototype* that is searched for "**default values**" for an objects properties.

```
function MyConstructor() { /* example function or "class" */ }
```

The above statement creates an **object** named `MyConstructor`, which has an *instance prototype* that is a reference to `Function.prototype`. At the same time, it is also a function that you can invoke.

**This is important:**

```
MyConstructor instanceof Function;
// is TRUE because
Object.getPrototypeOf(MyConstructor) === Function.prototype

// this is NOT TRUE
MyConstructor.prototype === Function.prototype
```

**Because of this subtle difference**

```
var myInstance = new MyConstructor();

myInstance instanceof MyConstructor;
// this is TRUE because
Object.getPrototypeOf(myInstance) === MyInstance.prototype
```

Now, `MyConstructor.prototype` is simply an empty object (which has an *instance prototype* referring to `Object.prototype`).

**Accessing properties**

In javascript, a objects only have properties. They don't have methods, but they have properties  that *point to a function*.

When you try to access a property on an object (instance of `Base`), the engine looks for that property like this:

| Checked location | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `this.$HERE$` | On your local properties |
| `this.__proto__.$HERE$` | `__proto__` is a reference to `Base.prototype`. |
| `this.__proto__.__proto__.$HERE$` | This would be your *parent* class prototype. |
| `this.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.$HERE$` | This would be your *grand-parent* class prototype. |
| ...and on we go, searching through the *prototype chain*, until there are no more prototypes. | The search is done using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`, which means that even if the value is `undefined`, the search will stop. |

> `__proto__` is a magic property which has been deprecated in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. I'm using it for brevity.

Any property found via the prototype chain, will be *bound* to `this` before it is returned to you.

Next comes inheritance and method definitions. There are two schools of thought here; one overwrites the `Base.prototype` with a new object, created with `Object.create`, and then proceed to create methods:

```
// This works (but it overwrites the Base.prototype object)
Base.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass);

// Declare a method
Base.prototype.incrementMyValue = function() {
    this.myValue++;
}

// A default value
Base.prototype.myValue = 123

// A getter
Object.defineProperty(Base.prototype, 'getMyValue', {get: function() { 
  return myValue;
}});
```

In the above code, I would like to point out that when you access `instance.myValue` it will be undefined, so the prototype chain is scanned and you'll get `123`.

If you call `instance.incrementMyValue()` *for the first time*, the prototype chain will be scanned and return 123. Then you increment the value, and it is assigned *to your instance*.

You started with:

```
instance // no .myValue exists
instance.__proto__.myValue = 123
```

Calling:

```
instance.incrementValue();
```

You end up with:

```
instance.myValue = 124;
instance.__proto__.myValue = 123
```

The default value exists still, but it is overridden by the instance local `myValue` property.

### The *old-school* class definition with inheritance

This class has it all:

- private properties
- private static properties
- public properties
- public static properties

Behold, the "Charm" class, lending ideas from my Charm.js library that I hope to publish:

```
var Derived = (function(){
  /* Wrapped in a function, so we keep things private*/

  /**
   * CONSTRUCTOR
   */
  function Derived(id, name) {
    Base.call(this, id);               // Calling the parent constructor
    private(this).name = name;         // Setting a TRUE private property
  }

  /**
   * PRIVATE STATIC PROPERTIES
   */
  var thisIsPrivateAndShared = 0;

  /**
   * PUBLIC STATIC PROPERTIES
   */
  Derived.thisIsPublicAndShared = 0;

  /**
   * PRIVATE NON-STATIC PROPERTIES THROUGH WeakMap
   */
  var secrets = new WeakMap();
  function private(for) {
    var private = secrets.get(for);
    if (!private) {
      private = {};
      secrets.set(for, private);
    }
    return private;
  }

  /**
   * Building the prototype
   */
  Derived.prototype = Object.create(

    /**
     * EXTEND Base.prototype (instead of Object.prototype)
     */
    Base.prototype,

    /**
     * Declare getters, setters, methods etc (or see below)
     */
    {
      /**
       * GETTERS AND SETTERS FOR THE PRIVATE PROPERTY 'name'
       */
      name: {
        get: function() {                // getter
          return private(this).name;
        },
        set: function(value) {           // setter
          private(this).name = value;
        }
      },

      /**
       * A PUBLIC METHOD
       */
      method: {value: function() {

      }},

      /**
       * A PUBLIC PROPERTY WITH A DEFAULT VALUE
       */
      age: {value: 42, writable: true}
    });

    /**
     * I am too lazy to write property descriptors,
     * unless I want a getter/setter/private properties,
     * so I do this:
     */
    Derived.prototype.lessWorkMethod = function() {
    };
  }
  return Derived;
})();
```

Comment: function Base(id) {
  // GOOD
  this.id = id;

  // GOOD, because we need to create a NEW array for each
  this.tags = [];

  // Okay, but could also just be in the prototype
  this.numberOfInteractions = 0;

  // BAD
  this.didInteract = function() {
    this.numberOfInteractions++;
  }
}

This just seems to work, why shouldn't we do this? (the example with BAD)

Comment: @gabn88 The BAD example creates a new closure every time you create a new object. It is extra work having to be done by the computer, and it wastes energy and increases energy prices. If your script is run 1000 times per page, and you have a million users clicking 1000 pages each year - then that tiny job is done 1 000 000 000 000 times. One MILLION MILLION times. That's a large chunk of coal having to be burned around the world to produce electricity.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But regarding the functionality, it will be equal, right?

Comment: It will be equal unless you attach properties to the closure, or if you use the closure as a key in a Map, I suppose.

Comment: Hi frodeborli, in your example "Improved sugar coated version" of the `Base` class, I don't see `numberOfInteractions` in `Base.prototype`, while the function-version of it, has it. Do you know why that is?